# Is this table in 3NF?

Tags: normalization

I have a table `person` with attributes:

```
id
name
city
state
country
```

`id` is the primary key. Is this table in 3NF? If 1000 people live in same city it seems redundant to store the same data for state, city, and country.

Answer (score 6):

No it is not.

Consider this data

```
id | name | city        | state      | country
----------------------------------------------
 1 | john | Los Angeles | California | USA
 2 | mary | San Antonio | Texas      | USA
 3 | joe  | Los Angeles | California | USA
```

It is clear that (city,state,country) is a candidate key for another table.  Then, you would quickly realise that the cities belong to the same (state,country) combinations.  Eventually, you end up with

```
Person
------
id
name
city_id

City
--------
city_id
name
state_id

State
--------
state_id
name
country_id

Country
----------
country_id
name
```

Comment: If it's not in 3NF, there must be a transitive dependency. Where's the transitive dependency?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' - The argument goes that country depends on state and state depends on city.  Since the table shows these columns as being the key columns of the presumed geography entities, you're quite right that the strict definition of 3NF is preserved.  However, for practical purposes address data is notoriously bad (spelling/typos/etc).  The OP's table doesn't need to have geography normalized out as per this answer, but it probably should if the intention is to do any analysis on geography - not because 3NF demands it, but for the sake of sanity.

Comment: *"The argument goes that country depends on state and state depends on city."* That's not true, though, is it? State certainly doesn't depend on city in the USA; we have dozens of Springfields. There are Santa Cruzes all over the world. (Springfields, too.) A foreign key can eliminate spelling errors and typos, but that won't affect the normal form.  Any time you introduce an ID number--let alone three different ID numbers--in the name of normalization, you're almost certainly on the wrong track.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'Catcall' I guess it depends a little bit on your perspective.  I've worked in address data quality (amongst many other things) for nearly two decades.  Having dozens of Springfields could be considered an argument in favour of `city_id`.  While the string token "SPRINGFIELD" doesn't determine the state, the actual municipality called Springfield (whichever one it happens to be) _does_.  Whether or not that functional dependency _matters_ will vary from system to system.  If it doesn't matter in a particular system, then I couldn't agree with you more, `city_id` is be a bad idea.

Comment: Neither normalization nor 3NF depend on my perspective or on my opinion. 3NF depends on eliminating transitive dependencies. Where's the transitive dependency in the original table? Even if there *were* one, it wouldn't justify the decomposition we see in this answer. No principle of normalization justifies what we see in this answer.

Comment: @Mike Perhaps in the purest sense with just these 5 fields you may be right. I had half-assumed there were other attributes or perhaps in future more would be added to each distinct entity. City would have its own GPS location and mayor_id, State would have boundary (geo-polygon) etc. The transitive dependency then becomes clearer -> person (id) is related to country only by way of state and state through city. Transitive dependencies lead to redundant data hence the point of normalisation. If person is tie-broken using id, why doesn't it also apply to city_id?